# 2つのPCからフォルダを同じgithubのレポジトリにpushする際のエラー

Tags: git, github

git・githubを使い始めているのですが、いろいろうまく行かず調べても対処方が見つからない(知識が浅く調べ方が悪い)のでご存知の方アドバイス頂けると幸いです。

目的:今まで複数のPCで別々に開発してきたプログラムフォルダをgithubに入れて共有のようにしたい。
つまずいているところ:PC1で以下の方法でレポジトリにpushできました。その同じレポジトリにPC2(別PC)のプログラムを同じ方法でpushしたいのですが以下のエラーが出てしまいました。

過程

```
github上にあげたいフォルダまで行く
git init
git add .
git commit -m ""
git remote add origin https://github.com/…
git push origin master
```

エラー

> To https://github.com/….git  ! [rejected]       
>   master -> master (non-fast-forward) error: failed to push some refs to
>   'https://github.com/….git' hint: Updates were
>   rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind hint: its
>   remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g. hint: 'git pull
>   ...') before pushing again. hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards'
>   in 'git push --help' for details.

そもそもgithubの使用目的が正しくない、考え方が違う、手法が違うなどなにかアドバイス頂けると幸いです。

Comment: PC2 は git clone で始めた方が楽では...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

もしかしてPC2の方でも`git init`やってたりします？
その場合、どんなerrorが出るか試したことないので憶測になりますが...

PC1で

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "適切な変更履歴"
git remote add origin https://github.com/…
git push origin master
```

とやってあげた後に、PC2ではPC1で上げたrepositoryを取って来てやって...

```
git clone https://github.com/…
```

必要な修正を実施。変更をcommitしてpushするのが流れになります。なので、

```
git add .
git commit -m "適切な変更履歴"
git push origin master
```

だけすれば良いと思います。
この、PC2でのcloneからpushまでの間に、PC1からgithub上のrepositoryが更新(PC1で新たにpush)されてたら、PC2で

```
git pull origin master
```

が必要になるわけです。

---

まぁ、ホントはbranch切って作業してやるべきなんですが...
その辺は、http://www.backlog.jp/git-guide/ 辺りでも読んでみてください。

Comment: 丁寧なご回答本当にありがとうございます。試したところできたのですが、違うエラーがでて、恐らくファイルがサイズが大きすぎるのだと思います。また別でこのエラーは解消したいと思います。アドバイスありがとうごじます。

Answer (score 3):

**短い答え**: エラーメッセージの内容を恐れず読解し、PC2 で `git pull origin master` を実行してみましょう

**長い答え**:

ここでの登場人物として PC1, PC2, GitHub と3者が登場していますね

質問にある、PC1 でGitHub にPush した状態では... PC1, GitHub は同じ版管理状態ですが しかし、PC2 はその変更に対して追従できていません

この状態のまま、PC2 で別の作業を実施し保存した場合、「差分に追従していないのに GitHub にPC2 側の変更をGitHub に届けようとしている」不完全な版管理状態になります

これではPC1, PC2 どちらかの状態しか維持できなくなってしまいます

そのため 最初に、先に変更された差分を、 `git pull` によってPC2 は取り入れる必要があります

Comment: 私のような初心者でも理解できるわかりやすい解説、本当にありがとうございます。git pull origin masterを試し、PC2に差分(PC1でpushしたフォルダ)がpullされていること確認し、再度上述と同じ方法を行ったのですが同じエラーが出てしまいました。再度アドバイスを頂けると幸いです。

Comment: あとは、 `git status` コマンドで現在の状態を確認してみると、どう対処すればいいか判るかもしれませんよ